# How do I change a cell value based on a form submission?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, eventtrigger

I'm trying to build a cost calculator.

Based on a Google form submission, a new row is added to my google sheet.

Once the row is added, information on another tab should be changed automatically based on the name of the person who filled out the form (so far, I can change the info by selecting their name from a dropdown on the same tab).

A 3rd tab shows a receipt that should be emailed as a PDF to the person who filled the form. This tab is a summary of information based on the 2nd tab, which does mostly calculations.

So far I have only made the connections between the tabs, information changes based on the name of the person. But it should change automatically when a new row is added, and not manually from a dropdown + save 3rd tab as PDF + send email.
Not really sure how to make this trigger onFormSubmit, since most answers i could find were for email text only and info on how to save a sheet a PDF ran a for loop which i don't think will work too.

Any info is very welcome :)

[First Tab named "Form Responses 1" with raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGzW9.png)

[Second Tab named "Tour Calculator". Changes content when selecting band name from the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovlka.png)

[Third Tab named "PDF", gathers all information from the 2nd tab and displays it using a VLOOKUP, this tab should be sent as a PDF.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFhsy.png)

I got some lines of code to send the email but not sure how to trigger the band name (from 2) to change automatically for new submits.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.appendRow(e.values)
}
```